# Forcing Windows 10 Hot-Spot on with Powershell or Batch scipts?

Tags: windows-10, script, hotspot

Windows 10 got the Hot-Spot function, and we've got 5 laptops here which can work as hotspots.

Is there a way to force the hotspots on with each login with a .ps1 or .bat script?